# Exclude specific post from WP-feed

Tags: wordpress, video, jwplayer

I know that you can generate a feed using urls like: ?cat=3&feed=rss2

And you can switch it around to exclude the category 3 by putting a subtract sign in front: ?cat=-3&feed=rss2

But, it doesn't look like you can do the same for posts? I'm using the JW video Player and have loaded the related plugin. The related plugin can take an rss-feed (media rss) as the parameter so it can link to other videos/wordpress posts that are related.

My problem is that currently this means that the active video also appears in the related videos feed.

What would be the best solution for solving this problem? I aim to create my own rss feed generator in the future, but for now I just want to keep it simple and use the generated feeds that wordpress creates. Is there a simple way to add support for an url parameter named post for example? It could then take post=-7 to exclude post with id 7 from displaying in the feed.

Or is there better solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of explaining the mechanisem - there are many plugins just for that ..
One that I know is :

[StelthPubish](http://coffee2code.com/wp-plugins/stealth-publish/)

Edit I

I do not know about the URL - but you can try use the

```
function ok9_feed_filter($query) {
    if ( !$query->is_admin && $query->is_feed) {
        $query->set('post__not_in', array(15, 6) ); // page /post id
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'ok9_exclude_filter' );
```

or this

```
function ok9_feed_exlude($where, $wp_query = NULL) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( !$wp_query )
        global $wp_query;
    if ($wp_query->is_feed) {
        // exclude post id 
        $where .= " AND $wpdb->posts.ID NOT IN (15, 6)";
    }

    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where','ok9_feed_exlude', 1, 2 );
```

If you do not want to use a fixed id in the function - you can always add a custom field in the posts you want to exclude , and use that in the query ..

Comment: Hi, that is not what I asked for. I do not want the post to be stealth published or anything like that. The post should still show up in any normal feeds in any normal situation. What I want is to generate a feed with an url (similar to cat=-3&feed=rss2 (which ignores category 3 from the feed) but instead enforce a feed where post 7 (for example) is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function

```
    function exclude_category($query){
    if ( $query->is_home  || $query->is_feed || $query->is_archive ) {
        $query->set('cat', '-1');
    }
    return $query;
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

see'a